Подключение к стриму RabbitMQ (AMQP) из Flutter приложения, ошибка consumer prefetch count is not set for 'queue
Всем доброго времени суток.
Я начинающий во флаттере, и столкнулся с проблеммой.
Я разрабатываю приложение для андроид и айос.
В приложении будет экран, на котором будут данные, которые я получаю из СТРИМА  брокера сообщений (RabbitMQ, AMQP 0.9.1).
Когда я подключаюсь к обычной очереди - всё в порядке, всё работает, уходит и приходит.
Но когда я пытаюсь подключится к стриму, получаю ошибку

E/flutter (18563): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ChannelException(PRECONDITION_FAILED): PRECONDITION_FAILED - consumer prefetch count is not set for 'queue 'ENBfqmhud95FsU5VwmRrvp0mDY-5e4wlLk5XApzMF7M' in vhost '/''

Вроде бы не хватает prefetch, но я нигде в стримах не указываю явно prefetch. Да и на сервере (в менеджинге) никаких дополнительных аргументов у стрима нет.
Вот мой код в дарте:
    _channel = await _clientGet.channel();
 await _channel.qos(0, 100, global: true);
 Queue queue = await _channel.queue(AppConstants.queueName, durable: true, arguments: <String, Object>{'x-queue-type': 'stream'});
 Consumer consumer = await queue.consume(noAck: false, arguments: <String, Object>{"prefetch": 100});
 consumer.listen((AmqpMessage message) {
   // setState(() {
   //  _updateLocation();
   // });
   print('xxxReceived message: ${message.payloadAsString}');
 });

Я уже пробовал(по ощущениям) всё что можно было, но ни информации, ни примера, ни решения не нашёл. Уже 2 дня борюсь с этими стримами.
Вот пример кода из фронта(JS), который подключается к этим же стримам:
const amqp = new AMQPWebSocketClient(element.mapRow.getAttribute('data-rabbitmq-url'), "/", element.mapRow.getAttribute('data-rabbitmq-user'), element.mapRow.getAttribute('data-rabbitmq-pass'))
const conn = await amqp.connect()
if(!conn) throw new Error('No connect to RMQ');
const ch = await conn.channel()
let mainQueue = await ch.queue(queueName, {}, {"x-queue-type": "stream" })
let reverseQueue = await ch.queue(queueName + reversePrefix, {}, {"x-queue-type": "stream" })
const consumer = await mainQueue.subscribe({ noAck: false, args: { "x-stream-offset": "last" } }, (msg) => {
...
 }
}

П.С: изменить стримы на обычные очереди нельзя, на них держится фронт в проде.

have you resolve it?

_channelGet = await _clientGet.channel();  await _channelGet.qos(null, 10000, global: false);  queueGet = await _channelGet.queue(mainQueueName,         durable: true, arguments: <String, Object>{'x-queue-type': 'stream'});  consumerGet = await queueGet.consume(         noAck: false, arguments: <String, Object>{'x-stream-offset': 'last'});   
да, просто дефолтные параметры в библиотеках под разные языки отличаются. Нужно указывать всё.

thank you for your answer

@АндрейЛевченко создайте ответ на ваш вопрос и отмете его как решённый.
